# How to use SELECT parameters assignments in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, parameters

I've been migrating MSSQL DB into MySQL and facing a syntax I cannot find anywhere and need this help.
All "MySQL parameters" question deals with "select * from mytable where id = @id" but I'm looking for the below syntax:

```
SELECT @MyParam = MyValue FROM MyTable
```

While "SELECT MyValue FROM MyTable" returns values, running the above @MyParam query returns NULLs.

From previous answers I see that as opposed to MSSQL, in MySQL the parameters aren't predefined with any datatype.

What am I missing here?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:=` operator instead of `=`, when you are assigning value to a user-defined variable in the `SELECT` clause. Former is assignment operator; while the latter is comparison operator.

```
SELECT @MyParam := MyValue FROM MyTable
```

However, if you are using `SET` clause, then you can use either `=` or `:=`. From [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> For SET, either = or := can be used as the assignment operator.

More from the docs:

> When making an assignment in this way (using `SELECT`), you must use
>   := as the assignment operator; = is treated as the comparison operator
>   in statements other than SET.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. I should have thought on this (though I'm MSSQL fan forced to move to MySQL..) Thx so much.

Comment: The `:=` format with `SELCECT` will cause extra result set from the procedure. Use `SELECT col INTO vVariable` syntax instead.

Answer (score 1):

When converting MS SQL Server procedures to MySQL procedures, you better use local variables declared with `DECLARE`.

The `@var` variables are user-defined variable and the scope is the process. So if your procedures call other procedures, the variable value may change whereas local variables will not. Local variables also have a defined type.

To convert MS SQL Server syntax

```
SELECT @MyParam = MyValue FROM MyTable
```

into MySQL, usee:

```
DECLARE vMyParam int;
SELECT MyValue INTO vMyParam FROM MyTable;
```

The format:

```
SELECT @MyParam := MyValue FROM MyTable
```

will cause an extra result set from the procedure so that is probably something you do not want.

You can use the `:=` format when you use `SET`-command where you explicitly set a value for a variable.

```
SET vMyParam = 10;
```

Comment: thanks for clarifying this. Just tested it and it worked perfectly. Thx